# How to get file size without holes in C

Tags: c, file, unix, dirent.h

So I was trying to get the size of a file in C.

I am aware of 2 ways of getting a file size in C, to use the `st_size` member of the `stat` structure or use `fseek` between the beginning and end of the file.

However, I was concerned with whether the `st_size` method would report the "false size" of a file if it has holes.
I'd imagine the `fseek` method would definitely produce the incorrect result if the file has holes, correct?

According to the book "Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment", section 4.12, one way of getting around this is to copy the file into memory and reading its size from memory. But I couldn't figure out how to do this in C so I was wondering how exactly you could do that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How exactly do you define a hole?

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by 'without holes'? If you mean the Unix practice of not storing complete blocks of zero bytes, those non-stored bytes are just as much a part of the file as any other. Why would you not want to count them? If you want the `du` size, `du` already exists.

Comment: The `du` size, incidentally, is computed from the `st_blocks` member of `stat`.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding that passage in Stevens.

Comment: You certainly are. It doesn't say any such thing. It says the *opposite.* If you read a file with holes, the holes are populated with zero bytes. Counting the result of doing that gives you the same result as `st_size`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean "holes" between physical blocks on disk where the file's data is stored - those don't count as part of the file, and both methods will only regard proper file data. In the file abstraction, there are no "holes".

Comment: thanks for the speedy reply but what about [this example](https://imgur.com/a/BpbhMws)
.Also from the same book I mentioned earlier. It is accessing files from the filesystem and yet it presents holes in the file size output.

Comment: @AbdelsalamElTamawy: You left out the link.

Comment: sorry about that. fixed it.

Comment: Well, as you can see in your own example - the abstract file size and the actual disk usage are different things. Empty, uniform or uninitialized blocks can exist without using up disk pages... that doesn't change my answer though. Consider adding that image and explanation to your question; or perhaps - restate the question so that you're asking about the amount of disk space used by a file, not the "file size".